# ChromeでDNSを含めたすべてのキャッシュを無効化する方法は？

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chromeで特定のサイトに対してDNSキャッシュ、ページキャッシュなどすべてのキャッシュをクリア、あるいは無効化する方法はあるでしょうか？

DNS設定を変更した後にキャッシュが残ってしまいDNS変更が反映されず困っています。

#OS側のDNSキャッシュはクリア済みです。

Comment: タイトルと書き出しの文章からは、DNSのキャッシュなのかコンテンツなのかわかりづらいですね。

Comment: 質問内容を更新しました。説明不足すみません。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windowsであれば「F12」、Macであれば「Cmd + Alt + i」を押すことで表示されるデベロッパーツール上で、右上にある歯車アイコンを押した後に表示される設定画面内にある、「Disable cache (while DevTools is open)」にチェックを入れると、デベロッパーツールが表示されている限りはキャッシュが無効化されます。

以下の記事に該当部分のスクリーンショットが上がっているので、併せて参考にしてみてください。
http://qiita.com/cubdesign/items/dca4d933539235bb5f11

Comment: うまくいきました。この方法で私のしたかったことができたので回答マークを付けさせていただきます。みなさんありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

chrome://net-internals/#dns にアクセスして clear host cache ボタンをクリックすればDNSキャッシュのクリアができます。

Comment: 素早いレスポンスありがとうございます。教えていただいた方法をやってみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。まだ旧サイトが表示されます。DNSキャッシュとは別のキャッシュが残っているのでしょうか？ただ、閲覧履歴の全削除はやりたくないのでやっていません。特定サイトだけキャッシュ(DNSやページコンテンツなどすべてのキャッシュです)をクリアするか、キャッシュなしでアクセスできる方法があればよいのですが。。

Comment: 全キャッシュを無効にするのであれば、@kubosho_ さんが書かれているようにdeveloperToolsを使うのが簡単だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

既に確認されているとは思いますが、念のためDNSの設定変更が反映されている事は確認されているのでしょうか？
Windowsの場合コマンドプロンプトで

```
nslookup example.com
```

を実行した結果、期待するIPアドレスが返っていますか？
（example.comの部分は閲覧したいドメイン）

Comment: はい。nslookupにて確認済みです。記載不足すみません。

Answer (score 1):

「DNS設定を変更」というのはIPアドレスを変えたという事でしょうか。
tsu.example.com を 旧 203.0.113.1 から 新 203.0.113.2 に変えたと言うような。

nslookupでは 203.0.113.2 になっている事を確認した、とコメントされていますし、
Chromeでも chrome://net-internals/#dns を別タブで開いたまま tsu.example.com を表示すれば、chrome://net-internals/#dns ページ内に どのIPアドレスとして読んでいるかリストされているはずですが、それも確認したらしいコメントが有りました。

chrome://view-http-cache/ には キャッシュされているデータのURLがリストされていますので tsu.example.com のコンテンツキャッシュが存在するかわかると思います。

これもうまくいかないということであれば、
では Google Chromeで 直接 203.0.113.2 へアクセスした場合に 新コンテンツが表示されるでしょうか。